# Can anyone help me with the r shiny code?

Tags: r, database, shiny, error-handling, visualization

I have written this code to analyze the cars dataset; the code generates an error in the app " Object, object."

The code is a Shiny app that allows the user to select a question from a drop-down menu and then visualizes the answers to that question using a bar plot.

The dataset file can be found here:

https://www.kaggle.com/CooperUnion/cardataset/data

The R-Shiny code for this solution is as follows:

```
library(magrittr) 
library(dplyr) 

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Car Data Visualization"),
 
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     selectInput(inputId = "question",
                 label = "Select a Question",
                 choices = c("1. What are the most popular car models?",
                             "2. What are the most popular car brands?",
                             "3. What are the most popular car types?",
                             "4. What are the most popular car colors?",
                             "5. What are the most popular car features?",
                             "6. What are the most popular car price ranges?"))
   ),
   
   mainPanel(
     plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
   )
 )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
 
 output$plot <- renderPlot({
   
   if (input$question == "1. What are the most popular car models?") {
     
     data <- read.csv("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/data.csv")
     
     models <- data %>%
       group_by(model) %>%
       summarise(sales = n(),
                 reviews = sum(reviews),
                 rating = mean(rating)) %>%
       arrange(desc(sales))
     
     plot(models$sales,
          type = "bar",
          main = "Most Popular Car Models",
          xlab = "Model",
          ylab = "Sales")
     
   } else if (input$question == "2. What are the most popular car brands?") {
     
     data <- read.csv("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/data.csv")
     
     brands <- data %>%
       group_by(brand) %>%
       summarise(sales = n(),
                 reviews = sum(reviews),
                 rating = mean(rating)) %>%
       arrange(desc(sales))
     
     plot(brands$sales,
          type = "bar",
          main = "Most Popular Car Brands",
          xlab = "Brand",
          ylab = "Sales")
     
   } else if (input$question == "3. What are the most popular car types?") {
     
     data <- read.csv("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/data.csv")
     
     types <- data %>%
       group_by(type) %>%
       summarise(sales = n(),
                 reviews = sum(reviews),
                 rating = mean(rating)) %>%
       arrange(desc(sales))
     
     plot(types$sales,
          type = "bar",
          main = "Most Popular Car Types",
          xlab = "Type",
          ylab = "Sales")
     
   } else if (input$question == "4. What are the most popular car colors?") {
     
     data <- read.csv("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/data.csv")
     
     colors <- data %>%
       group_by(color) %>%
       summarise(sales = n(),
                 reviews = sum(reviews),
                 rating = mean(rating)) %>%
       arrange(desc(sales))
     
     plot(colors$sales,
          type = "bar",
          main = "Most Popular Car Colors",
          xlab = "Color",
          ylab = "Sales")
     
   } else if (input$question == "5. What are the most popular car features?") {
     
     data <- read.csv("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/data.csv")
     
     features <- data %>%
       group_by(feature) %>%
       summarise(sales = n(),
                 reviews = sum(reviews),
                 rating = mean(rating)) %>%
       arrange(desc(sales))
     
     plot(features$sales,
          type = "bar",
          main = "Most Popular Car Features",
          xlab = "Feature",
          ylab = "Sales")
     
   } else if (input$question == "6. What are the most popular car price ranges?") {
     
     data <- read.csv("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/data.csv")
     
     prices <- data %>%
       group_by(price) %>%
       summarise(sales = n(),
                 reviews = sum(reviews),
                 rating = mean(rating)) %>%
       arrange(desc(sales))
     
     plot(prices$sales,
          type = "bar",
          main = "Most Popular Car Price Ranges",
          xlab = "Price Range",
          ylab = "Sales")
     
   }
   
 })
 
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
the generated app shows error: [ object, object ]
```

Comment: Will you be able to modify the code a bit so that the community may execute the posted code. for example : data <- read.csv("C:/Users/asus/Downloads/data.csv") ==> data = data.frame (.....)

Comment: Hard to say without having the cars data. Are you sure that all plots are working outside shiny? Try using `switch` instead of the nested if else.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this shiny would have issues simply because it doesn't have a generalizable CSV reader function.

Comment: I have updated the question with the dataset link